# How can I chain animations in anime.js?

Tags: javascript, anime.js

Is there any way to chain animations in anime.js or have queues / groups of animations that I can wait for in order to proceed with other animations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each animation with `anime` returns a promise, so you can use `async/await` in combination with `Promise.all`, do remember, though, `Promise.all` makes it so that all animations run concurrently. For example, let's say you want 3 animations all to run at the same time, then, after that group is done, do another animation:

```js
async function animateLockAndBackground() {
  const bigLockAnimation = anime({
    targets: '#big-lock',
    strokeDashoffset: [0, 5],
    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
    duration: 250,
    easing: 'easeInSine'
  }).finished;

  const lockLineAnimation = anime({
    targets: '#lock-line',
    strokeDashoffset: [0, 3],
    translateY: [{
        value: '-2px',
        duration: 350,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
      },
      {
        value: '2px',
        duration: 350,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
      },
      {
        value: '-2px',
        duration: 350,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
      },
    ],
  }).finished;

  const innerCircleAnimation = anime({
    targets: '#inner-circle',
    translateY: [{
        value: '-1px',
        duration: 250,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
      },
      {
        value: '1px',
        duration: 250,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
      },
      {
        value: '-1px',
        duration: 250,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
      },
      {
        value: 0,
        duration: 250,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
      },
    ],
  }).finished;

  await Promise.all([bigLockAnimation, lockLineAnimation, innerCircleAnimation]);
}

animateLockAndBackground().then(() => {
  console.log('First animation finished.');
  anime({
    targets: '.plugins-not-installed-text',
    translateY: [{
      value: '10px',
      duration: 750
    }]
  });
  anime({
    targets: '#lock-wrapper',
    translateY: [{
      value: '-10px',
      duration: 750
    }]
  });
  anime({
    targets: '#plugins-not-installed-screen',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'linear'
  }).finished.then(() => {
    console.log('Second animation finished.');
  });
});
```

```css
#plugins-not-installed-screen {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#plugins-not-installed-screen .upper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 24px 48px;
    background-image: url('../Images/component.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

.plugins-not-installed-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#lock {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 65px;
}

#plugins-not-installed-screen #lock {}

#plugins-not-installed-screen #big-lock {
  stroke-dasharray: 61 62;
  stroke-dashoffset: 5;
  /* go to 5 */
}

#plugins-not-installed-screen #lock-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 31 33;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  /* go to 3 */
}

#components-to-install-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.install-component-individual {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animejs@3.1.0/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
<div id="plugins-not-installed-screen" class="">
  <div class="upper">
    <div id="lock-wrapper">
      <svg version="1.1" id="lock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 25 35" style="enable-background:new 0 0 25 35;" xml:space="preserve">
          <style type="text/css">
              #big-lock{fill:none;stroke:#686868;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
              #inner-circle{fill:none;stroke:#686868;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
              #lock-line{fill:none;stroke:#686868;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
          </style>
          <path id="big-lock" d="M4.4,13.5c-1.2,0.8-2,2.1-2,3.6v4c0,2.8,1.1,5.4,3.1,7.4c1.9,1.9,4.5,2.9,7.2,2.9
              c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3,0c5.5-0.1,10-4.9,10-10.5v-3.8c0.1-1.8-0.9-3.3-2.4-4l-6.5-2.7c-0.8-0.3-1.8-0.4-2.6,0L10.1,11"/>
          <circle id="inner-circle" cx="12.7" cy="21.9" r="2.9"/>
          <path id="lock-line" d="M7.1,15.1V9.9c0-3.1,2.5-5.6,5.6-5.6h0c3.1,0,5.6,2.5,5.6,5.6v8"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <h5 class="plugins-not-installed-text">Plugins not installed.</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

What, then, if you want to, inside that function, have the `lock-line` animate at the same time the 2 other elements are animating, so instead of 3 animation timelines, you only have 2? Here:

```
async function animateLockAndBackground() {
    const bigLockAnimation = anime({
        targets: '#big-lock',
        strokeDashoffset: [0, 5],
        easing: 'easeInOutSine',
        duration: 250,
        easing: 'easeInSine'
    }).finished;

    const innerCircleAnimation = anime({
        targets: '#inner-circle',
        translateY: [
            {value: '-1px', duration: 250, easing: 'easeOutExpo'},
            {value: '1px', duration: 250, easing: 'easeOutExpo'},
            {value: '-1px', duration: 250, easing: 'easeOutExpo'},
            {value: 0, duration: 250, easing: 'easeOutExpo'},
        ],
    }).finished;

    await Promise.all([bigLockAnimation, innerCircleAnimation]);
}

animateLockAndBackground().then(() => {
    return anime({
        targets: '#lock-line',
        strokeDashoffset: [0, 3],
        translateY: [
            {value: '-2px', duration: 350, easing: 'easeOutExpo'},
            {value: '2px', duration: 350, easing: 'easeOutExpo'},
            {value: '-2px', duration: 350, easing: 'easeOutExpo'},
        ],
    }).finished;
}).then(() => {
    anime({
        targets: '.plugins-not-installed-text',
        translateY: [
            {value: '10px', duration: 750}
        ]
    });
    anime({
        targets: '#lock-wrapper',
        translateY: [
            {value: '-10px', duration: 750}
        ]
    });
    anime({
        targets: '#plugins-not-installed-screen',
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'linear'
    });
});
```

We moved that `lock-line` animation outside of the original group, made it wait for the group, then whatever else comes after the `lock-line` animates after.

You should think about an animation as a simple promise that you can chain.

Answer (score 7):

Try the timeline function: https://animejs.com/documentation/#timelineBasics
You can do all the promise stuff yourself if you want but anime already handles it so there really isn't any point in it. Making a timeline function chains animations together and you can even force it to before the previous animation finishes by adding a time to the .add function `.add({ //your animation }, time)` or relative offsets with `.add({ //your animation }, -/+ = time)` (*plus or minus not both)

Comment: I feel like this is the modern solution to this question.